# Django - How to get the value of a decimal field of object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-queryset

I have looked through the QuerySet API reference and I couldn't find anything that allowed me to get the actual value, as a decimal, of a field of a specific object.

Everything I've tried doesn't return it as the actual decimal value. For example, Hours.objects.filter(fullname=fullname).values(hours) doesn't return the number of hours as a decimal value. I'm trying to get the number of hours of a user, mathematically add a number to it (e.g. 15.5 + 4.25) and save it back (as 19.75).

Comment: What does your Hours model look like?

Comment: It should be `.values("hours")` (note the quotes) for starters. Without posting your `models.py` we can't say anything more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly you need to filter objects in Hours table and update it value.

First of all note that this `result = Hours.objects.filter(fullname=fullname).values('hours')` return list of dicts, not list of Decimal. So if you need to get `hours` you should do this `hour = result[0].get('hours')`. But after this you cannot do `hours = hours + 1.5`. Because `hours` has [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) type and you should to convert 1.5 which is float to Decimal first:

```
import decimal

result = Hours.objects.filter(fullname=fullname).values('hours')
hour = result[0].get('hours')
hour_difference = decimal.Decimal(1.5)
hour = hour + hour_difference
```

But with Django you can make updates much easier. Just use [update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#update):

```
    Hours.objects.filter(fullname=fullname).update(hours=20.5)
```

If you need to increment current value then you can do it with [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#f-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import F

Hours.objects.filter(fullname=fullname).update(hours=F('hours') + 1.5)
```

this will get all Hours object related with filter add to it's `hours` field `1.5` and save it.